# The mechanics of populating an array

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic-arrays, populate

I tried to populate an array of structs defined as follows:

```
typedef struct{
    char directive[5];
}directive_nfo_t;
```

By using the following:

```
directive_nfo_t directive_list[]=
{
   {"ALIGN"},{"ASCII"},{"BSS"},{"BYTE"},{"END"},{"EQU"},{"ORG"}
};
```

To my surprise, the first few elements were corrupted like so:

```
[0]= ALIGNASCIIBSS
[1]= ASCIIBSS
[2]= BSS
...
```

Until I made the following change:

```
typedef struct{
    char directive[6];  <-- made char array +1
}directive_nfo_t;
```

Then the first few arrays were correct like so:

```
[0]= ALIGN
[1]= ASCII
[2]= BSS
...
```

My question is what happens in the background to explain this behavior? 
Regards.

Comment: "ALIGN" needs 6 chracters, not 5.

Comment: You didn't give space for the null terminators.

Comment: your elements are not corrupted, you're displaying them wrong (probably via %s which expects null-terminated string), but you have char arrays (which is not the same)

Comment: How are you looking at the data?

Comment: @SergeyA - your response did not answer my question.

Comment: @johannes - thru the debugger.

Comment: RTFM: In C, the constant "ALIGN" is a six-character array, containing 'A', 'L', 'I', 'G', 'N', and '\0'.

Comment: @lee Daniel Crocker: RTFQ - "What happens in the background?"  Thanks to all that posted answers to the actual question.

Comment: In this case, since you've asked it to put six gallons of water in a five-gallon bucket, it just puts in five gallons and moves on. And since that missing bit is a string terminator, that ends up putting strings in consecutive memory with no terminators.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker - Thank you. That is actually a very good analogy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you explicitly initialize a `char` array as string literal in the way you do:

```
char some_array[] = {"ALIGN"};
```

the compiler actually populates the *0th* to *4th* "position" (total of 5 positions) with the characters inside quotation marks, but also the *fifth position* with `\0` without requiring you do it explicitly (if it has space enough). So the size equals 6. You exceed the boundaries if you don't count the `\0` character into the size calculation and restrict the size to `5`. Compiler would omit the terminating character.

In your case it looks as if the first element of the next member "overwrote" what should have been the *omitted* `\0` character of the previous, since you haven't reserved a place for it. In fact the "mechanics of populating the array" boils down to the compiler writing as much data as could fit inside the boundaries. The address of the first position of the next member string logically corresponds to your assignment, although the `\0` from the previous is missing.

Since your `printf()` *format tag* was `%s`, the function printed the characters until it reached the first `\0` character, which is in fact undefined behavior.

That's why

```
char directive[6];
```

was correct size assignment in your code.

Comment: The compiler did not "overwrite a `'\0'` character" and there is no overlap. It was never there in the first place. The C complier does not create array elements which are out of bounds.

Comment: No, it does check the bounds at compile time. Try it. If the text length is `5` and the array length is `5` it simply omits the terminator. You can exceed the bounds of an array at runtime (causing undefined behaviour), but not at compile time.

Comment: Thanks @Weather Vane, corrected.

Answer (score 13):

In C, a *string* is a sequence of character values followed by a 0-valued terminator; the *string* `"ASCII"` is represented by the character sequence `'A'`, `'S'`, `'C'`, `'I'`, `'I'`, `0`. Thus, you need a *six*-element array to store the string.

For a string that's `N` characters long, you need an array of `N+1` characters to store it.

Comment: I thought it had something to do with that. Thank you.

Comment: The array only has 5 elements. How is it fitting "ALIGNASCIIBSS" into it?

Comment: @Darrell: it does not. You assume it does because you use the wrong way of viewing what's "in" it.

Comment: @Rad Technically he's using the "right" way to view it, at least as far as C is concerned. Since it's a struct, containing a single 5 element of array, the compiler likely just shove them end to end when placed in an array. Since the rule of string in C is to print from the starting memory until it hits '\0', and all the five character words have their ending '\0' erased by the next element, C just keep printing until it sees a '\0'

Comment: @SterlingW: but that's exactly my point! Viewing them with something like `%s` is the wrong way *because* they are not null terminated strings.

Comment: @Darrell: The `s` specifier tells `printf` to print each character starting at specified address until it sees the 0 terminator; since your first two strings did not have 0 terminators, `printf` just kept on going into the second and then third character arrays.

Comment: I didn't use printf() or any other derivative of print to view the elements. Xcode displays variable contents when a break point is set. Who knows how Xcode retrieves the information. (rhetorical)

Comment: @Darrell: anything that displays C strings will work the same way; given a starting address, print characters in sequence until it sees the terminator.

Answer (score 2):

If the `char` array is big enough, C compiler automatically places a `'\0'` after the text.

If it is *just* large enough for the text, that terminator is omitted, which is what has happened here.

If there isn't even room for the text, the compiler will say something like "too many initialisers" or "array bounds overflow".

The struct array elements are adjacent in memory. The first two items lack a terminator, so the second item printed only stops at the terminator after the third item. The first item, is also printed until it reaches that same terminator. By making the array size 6, the compiler was able to place a terminator after every item.

Comment: The array only has 5 elements. How is it fitting "ALIGNASCIIBSS" into it?

Comment: @Darrell expanded my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike in C++, C allows you to (unintentionally) shoot yourself in the feet, by allowing to omit `NUL` terminating character `'\0'` in the `char` array initializer when there is no room for it. Your case can be narrowed down to a simple array definition such as:

```
char str[5] = "ALFAP";
```

which is a syntatic shortcut to:

```
char str[5] = {'A', 'L', 'F', 'A', 'P'};
```

It may be kind of misleading, because in different context the same `"ALFAP"` represets string literal, that always has the ending `NUL` character:

```
char* str = "ALFAP" // here, "ALFAP" always contains NUL character at the end
```

Comment: With great power comes great responsibility. In this instance, C grants you the capability to save 1 byte from the string (good thing if you're constrained for space and you only care for a large array of fixed-width strings). At the same time, you can use that power to blow your own head off.

Answer (score 1):

> My question is what happens in the background to explain this behavior? Regards.

You have an array of struct `directive_nfo_t` type and each struct `directive_nfo_t` holds array of five characters (in your first example). 
The output that you were getting when you have 5 character array in `directive_nfo_t` type was basically due to two things-

1. Array elements are stored in consecutive memory locations.
2. In C, the abstract idea of a string is implemented with just null terminated array of characters.

When you have declared an array of `directive_nfo_t` type, each element of `directive_nfo_t` is stored in consecutive memory location and each element has 5 character array(`which are also stored in consecutive locations`) in it. And in your Initialization list(`{"ALIGN"},{"ASCII"},{"BSS"},{"BYTE"},{"END"},{"EQU"},{"ORG"}`) for the array, you have used all the 5 characters in storing your data in first two elements of `directive_nfo_t` (`"ALIGN" and "ASCII"`). As, in C, functions which operate on character array to implement abstract idea of string, assume that a string will be terminated by using a null character at the end. Therefore, in the first two elements of `directive_nfo_t` array, the `printf` will keep on printing characters until it reaches null character(which it will find in element storing character array `"BSS"`). After printing `ALIGN`, `printf` will access the first character of second element of the array of `directive_nfo_t` (`character A of ASCII`). It occurred because there was not space for null character in the first element of array of `directive_nfo_t` type and compiler wouldn't add characters beyond array size as it does array bound check. From the third element of you array, you have enough space for null character and hence, `printf` works as expected.

You will get `UNDEFINED BEHAVIOR` if you allocate less memory to store your character array and use those functions which assume `null terminated character array`. Always set the size of the character array to `MAX + 1` when you want to store maximum `MAX` characters in your array.

Comment: Lesson learned "MAX+1". Thanks for the thorough and concise explanation.